# How do i know which decision tree model is better?

Tags: r, decision-tree

I did afew simple decision trees and produced 3 models. The 1st model m1 was completed without any modifications. The 2nd model m2 had a reduced minsplit of minsplit =2 . The 3rd model m3 was based on the 2nd model but pruned at the minimum cp.

Here are the confusion matrixs for the 3 models:

```
> print(cm1)
     
pred  No Yes
  No  14   2
  Yes  3  11
```

```
> print(cm2)
     
pred  No Yes
  No  17   0
  Yes  0  13
```

```
> print(cm3)
     
pred  No Yes
  No  16   2
  Yes  1  11
```

Here are the cptables for m2 and m3:

```
>m2$cptable
          CP nsplit rel error    xerror      xstd
1 0.61538462      0 1.0000000 1.0000000 0.2087816
2 0.05128205      1 0.3846154 0.6923077 0.1930754
3 0.03846154      4 0.2307692 0.6153846 0.1863169
4 0.00000000     10 0.0000000 0.7692308 0.1986145
```

```
> m3$cptable
          CP nsplit rel error    xerror      xstd
1 0.61538462      0 1.0000000 1.0000000 0.2087816
2 0.05128205      1 0.3846154 0.6923077 0.1930754
3 0.03846154      4 0.2307692 0.6153846 0.1863169
```

From these tables, my main question is **Which model is better and what comparsion parameters should i use to compare the models?**

Based on the tables alone I would use m2 as it does not give me any errors. However, m3 should be a better model as it was pruned at the minimum cp value. But m3 actually has a higher error rate here despite having a lower x-error.

Any advice would be great!

Comment: You are at the wrong site. You should ask this in https://stats.stackexchange.com/ or  https://datascience.stackexchange.com/ .

Comment: It doesn't look like you're using a lot of data. With such a small sample, have you thought about resampling methods? Additionally, one of the best ways to test model performance is to test model performance. Did you split the data into training and testing sample sets? If not, try that.